# What does typing.List<~T>[typing.Tuple[int]] mean in Python's typing lib?

Tags: python, typing

While playing with Python's `typing` module I came across something curious:

```
>>> from typing import List, Tuple
>>> List[Tuple[int]]
typing.List<~T>[typing.Tuple[int]]
```

What's this Java-like syntax `List<~T>`? What does it mean?

Comment: What do you mean *"where does it come from"*?

Comment: `List<~T>` is just a list of the generic type `T`, based on [the source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/typing.py#l489) `~` indicates neither co- nor contra-variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see:

```
typing.List<~T>[typing.Tuple[int]]
```

1. `typing.List` means *a type from the `typing` library, named `List`*
2. `<~T>` means *this type is generic, it's defined in terms of another type T*
3. `[typing.Tuple[int]]` means *type T is the type `Tuple[int]`*.

In natural language, you can read the definition like this:

> `typing.List<~T>[typing.Tuple[int]]`: a standard List of one-int tuples

Answer (score 4):

That's not actual Python syntax, so don't try to use it in a program. That said, this is how they chose to represent a generic type's type parameters. In a generic type's `repr`, the declared type parameters are listed in Java-like `<>` angle brackets, with a `+`, `-`, or `~` before each type parameter depending on whether that parameter is covariant, contravariant, or neither.

`typing.List` takes a single non-covariant, non-contravariant type parameter named `T`, so it gets a `<~T>` after the name.

You'll notice that `typing.Tuple` doesn't have any `<>` stuff after its name. `Tuple` is a weird special case, since it takes a variable number of type parameters.

Comment: The `<~T>` / `<+T>` / `<-T>` notations disappeared from python as of 3.6. It now just prints `typing.List[typing.Tuple[int]]`, so you can't see its variance. I couldn't find an issue related to that, otherwise I'd ask to bring it back :)